# How to find the code page when web scraping

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

i am trying to web scrape these pages [first one](https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Composition/45865) and [second one](https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Composition/70616).
I did something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

api_url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/GetCompoTableAndGraph"

dfs = {}
for compo in [1, 2, 3, 6]:
    payload = {'ID_Produit': 927355, 'typeCompo': compo}
    data = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
    dfs[compo] = pd.DataFrame(data['graph']['dataProvider'])
    dfs[compo] = dfs[compo].rename({'x' : 'date'}, axis=1).set_index('date')
```

I would like to know how to know which "typeCompo" should I use ie for the first one it is [4, 5, 8, 10] and for the second one it is [1, 2, 3, 6]. Where should I find the information on the site and assign compo in the right way except that do it with hands ie where is this information on the site to fix the typeCompo ?

Comment: From inspecting the websites provided, it looks like the tables have these numbers: e.g. `table1statistique` for when `typeCompo = 1` etc.  So you could write some code that retrieves the list of table numbers for each ID and use these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The logic that determines which values the page uses is inside JavaScript and HTML `<input>` element with `id="sTypeFonds"`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Composition/45865"
#url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Composition/70616"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
sTypeFonds = soup.select_one("#sTypeFonds")["value"]

# the logic inside javascript is this:
# switch (sTypeFonds) {
#     case 'ACTION':
#         loadElement("Geo", 1);
#         loadElement("Secto", 2);
#         loadElement("Capi", 3);
#         loadElement("Style", 6);
#         break;
#     case 'OBLIG':
#         loadElement("GeoOblig", 10);
#         loadElement("Duree", 4);
#         loadElement("Notation", 5);
#         loadElement("Emetteur", 8);
#         break;
#     default:
#         loadElement("Decompo", 7);
# }

if sTypeFonds == "ACTION":
    print([1, 2, 3, 6])
elif sTypeFonds == "OBLIG":
    print([10, 4, 5, 8])
else:
    print([7])
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6]
```